# Getting new accesstoken using the refreshtoken already retrieved in googledrive api

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am using Gooogledrive Api with php.Using it I have retrieved Refresh token from credentials part.The accesstoken expires after 3600 seconds.My question is how to get the new accesstoken from this refresh token.I have used the method given in Google php client library.I have called the refreshtoken('refreshtoke') function of apiclient.My code is following

```
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setClientId('my-client-id');
$client->setClientSecret('my client-secret-key');
$client->setRedirectUri('my redirect uri');



$client->refreshToken('MY-retrieved-refresh-token');
```

But I get the following error:-
 **Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }**.**

Please help me .Everything rest works fine.But accesstoken expires after 3600 seconds and is not refreshing

Comment: Do you set your access and refresh token? I don't see the line $client->SetAccessToken($tokens) where $tokens would be the access and refresh tokens in jSON.

Comment: Thanks vicrabb.I got your point.

Comment: Was it that or do you have still a problem?

Comment: Hi @vicrabb , I'm running into the same problem, can you please help me out with an example, there are so many things online, but non of them's clear. Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: When you need to refresh the tokens, you need them to be set. If you're not putting the line $client->SetAccessToken($tokens) (with $tokens holding your access and refresh tokens in jSON), you don't have the grants to refresh them. I don't have an example as I don't use the refreshToken() function.

Comment: Code look correct (see https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php) for how refresh works. Are you sure that the client ID/secret/redirect URI are correct? They need to match exactly what you used when the grant was first issued.

Answer (score 1):

//after this line of code

```
 $client->refreshToken('MY-retrieved-refresh-token');
```

//do this

```
 $token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

// this will give you json encode string which will have access, refresh token and bearer etc.

Comment: oh my....after nearly a full month of debugging this issue I had these two lines backwards. After switching them , things now work without having to re-authenticate every time the access token expires. Thank you so much for posting this Josh.