# Bad request when use refreshToken to get new accessToken by OAuth2 in PHP?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token, google-client

In PHP, I use OAuth2 to connect and save data to Google spreadsheet. After authenticating, I get refreshToken and accessToken.

In the first hour, accessToken is used and everything works fine.

When accessToken expired, I used refreshToken to get new accessToken. But I always receive the error "Bad request" instead of new accessToken.

How to fix this issue?

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken($acc_token);
```

First way:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
    $newAccessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $client->setAccessToken($newAccessToken);
}
```

Second way:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($refresh_token);
    $newAccessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $client->setAccessToken($newAccessToken);
}
```

I've tried some answers of the following questions but it's not solved my issue:

[Getting new accesstoken using the refreshtoken already retrieved in googledrive api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176330/getting-new-accesstoken-using-the-refreshtoken-already-retrieved-in-googledrive)

[Refresh Tokens Google OAuth 2.0 PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28270202/refresh-tokens-google-oauth-2-0-php?rq=3)